# Is there a way so that Criteria only matches dates and not timestamp?

Tags: hibernate, grails

I have data in one of the DB tables with column type `DATETIME`

It has entries like below:

```
2014-09-22 14:55:14
2014-09-22 16:20:05
2014-09-22 14:55:15
```

I take two parameters from the front end. Start date and end date. But at times users want to see all things created today. So they pass the same date for start and end when expecting all records created for a specific date (regardless of time).

But using the below criteria they get no records back.

```
def c = MyTable.createCriteria()
def count = c.count {
  gt ("dateCreated", new Date("9/22/2014)
  lt ("dateCreated", new Date("9/22/2014)  
}
```

**Question**

How can I write a criteria that takes two dates (start and end) and returns records from a `DATETIME` column while ignoring the time stamp. While supporting passing same date for start and end to get all records for the day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HQL there are date functions like `month()`, `day()` etc. so you can and them together and do your search.

In criteria there's only `sqlRestriction` to achieve that, but I think that that's ugly.

So, I'd recommend using a cleaner approach:

```
Date from = Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd', "2014-09-22")
from.clearTime() // call it, if from might have the hh:mm:ss section
Date to = from + 1

def c = MyTable.createCriteria()
def count = c.count {
  between "dateCreated", from, to
}
```

Comment: copied the original, and it WILL create a Date. But I wouldn't do it like that :)

Comment: what if `from` and `to` are same dates? will i get all records for that day?

Comment: @Dónal `groovy:000> new Date("9/22/2014").class
===> class java.util.Date`

Comment: @injecteer I've fixed it. There's no need to call `clearTime()` if there is no time component in the data being parsed

Comment: @birdy `from` and `to` can't be the same dates because `Date to = from + 1`

Comment: @birdy the distance betweeb `from` and `to` is exactly 1 day. this is what you originally specified in your code sample

Comment: @injecteer I don't think you can use `between` because you need to include "2014-09-22 0ms" and exclude "2014-09-23 0ms"

Comment: and the probability of such event is... according to original posting, it's not like the table gets new records each second

Comment: @injecteer the probability of incorrectly including/excluding a record may be low when using `between`, but it's very easy to eliminate this risk completely, so why not do it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this

```
Date from = Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd', "2014-09-22")

def count = MyTable.createCriteria().count {

  gte "dateCreated", from
  lt "dateCreated", from + 1
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use some of Groovy's date/time methods to give the start date a starting time of 12AM (0 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds), and the end date an ending time of 11:59:59 (23 hours, 59 minutes, 59 seconds).  Example:

```
import static java.util.Calendar.* //...needed to supply YEAR and MONTH

def rawEndDate = new Date() //...the user-supplied end date

def endDate = new Date()

endDate.set(

   year: rawEndDate[YEAR], 

   month: rawEndDate[MONTH], 

   date: rawEndDate.getDate(), 

   hourOfDay: 23, 

   minute: 59, 

   second: 59)
```

...then if you use those manipulated dates in your criteria, it won't matter if the user selected the same day for the start and end date: you'll still get the records with a creation date between the very start of the day and the very end of it.

Unfortunately, if there's a way to set the milliseconds as well - to set the start date with 0 milliseconds and the end date with 999 - I don't know about it.  When I had to tackle a similar problem recently, I had the freedom to manipulate the start and end date in JavaScript, and there I could set the milliseconds quite easily.

Some related references:

http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2010/06/groovy-goodness-use-set-method-to.html

http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN0545-Dates